# ERROR CONECTANDO A BD PHP 7

Tags: php, mysql, sql

estoy tratando de generar un archivo JSON, pero estoy sacando el ERROR 2, cuando trato de conectarme a la BD, mi hosting usa PHP7, no se si eso este influyendo en el error, antes funcionaba correctamente.

ERROR:

> Opps some thing went ERROR 2

Archivo PHP

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

$hostname = "host";
$user = "user";
$password = "****";
$database = "BD";

$db = mysqli_connect($hostname, $user, $password) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
mysqli_select_db($database, $db) or die("Opps some thing went ERROR 2");

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// get all items from myorder table


$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM escolar_tracker ") or die(mysqli_error());

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    $response["rutas"] = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            // temp user array
            $item = array();
            $item["id"] = $row["id"];
            $item["ruta"] = $row["ruta"];
            $item["jornada"] = $row["jornada"];

            // push ordered items into response array
            array_push($response["rutas"], $item);
           }
      // success
     $response["success"] = 1;
}
else {
    // order is empty
      $response["success"] = 0;
      $response["message"] = "No Items Found";
}
// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cuando utilizas mysqli_* deberas utilizar el identificador de la conexion como primer parametro de la siguiente forma

```
mysqli_select_db($db,$database);
```

lo mismo con

```
mysqli_query($db,statment);
```

Comment: Hola hioce la correcion, y ahora no me muestra nada la deje asi: `mysqli_select_db($db, $database) or die("Opps some thing went wrong2");`

Comment: entonces lo has hecho bien. pero tienes que aplicarlo tambien al mysqli_query te debe quedar como mysqli_query($db,'sql');

Comment: Si ya muchas gracias soy novato en php, asi lo hice y me dio venia a calificarte muy amable por tu tiempo